# How to get total timing of event time in minutes.

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using a material design datepicker. 
how to get timeing of event.
this is link of demo event

Bootstrap-Material-datepicker[1](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Pretty-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Material/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used last example of Bootstrap-Material-datepicker plugin where two datetime events **start date** and **end date** have been selected and now you want to find out difference of these two datetime events in minutes means (total time of event) , you can use javascript/jquery to calculate total time of events as follows:

After selecting start date (suppose 19/03/2018 20:30) and end date from (suppose 19/03/2018 22:40) Bootstrap-Material-datepicker, you can find total time as follows:

```
date1 = '19/03/2018 20:30';         // date selected by bootstrap material datepicker
date2 = '19/03/2018 22:40';

date1Arr = date1.split('/');        // Here, date is converted to array so that we can change format of date time which is accetable by Javascript
date1YearAndtime = date1Arr[2].split(" ");
newdate1 = date1YearAndtime[0]+"/"+date1Arr[1]+"/"+date1Arr[0]+" "+date1YearAndtime[1];                 // Combine array values to make it date format yyyy/mm/dd hour:minutes

date2Arr = date2.split('/');
date2YearAndtime = date2Arr[2].split(" ");
newdate2 = date2YearAndtime[0]+"/"+date2Arr[1]+"/"+date2Arr[0]+" "+date2YearAndtime[1];

var diff = Math.abs(new Date(newdate1) - new Date(newdate2));  // it finds difference between two dates in milliseconds

var minutes = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);        // Here, milliseconds is converted to seconds when divided by 1000 and then converted to minutes when divided by 60
alert(minutes);
```

If you have any question, you can ask.

Comment: this work fine. but can u explain more (line by line) please for better understanding.

Comment: Yes sure, I will explain each line